# Can someone explain: (+2 (if (>b a) b a))?

Tags: scheme, lisp

Started working through the exercises in *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* and I'm stuck on this in the first set of exercises.

```
a=3
b=4
(+ 2 (if (> b a) b a))
```

I've looked up the answer: 6  but, working through it myself, I can't figure out how to get that number.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply substitute the values to find out what is happening, so your expression is

```
(+ 2 (if (> 4 3) 4 3))
```

`(> 4 3)` compares if 4 is greater than 3, and of course it is so that becomes `true`

```
(+ 2 (if true 4 3))
```

`(if true 4 3)` will evaluate to 4 if the condition is true otherwise 3 so in this case we get 4 which leaves

`(+ 2 4)` which is just adding 2 and 4 which is 6